# Complex bean validation

Tags: bean-validation

How can I validate the below class using validator (JSR303) API? This should be done using Hibernate Validator API.

Suppose `TesterBatters` class itself has some validation. How can I validate those?

```java
public class Example {
    private String jseId;
    private String jseType;
    private String jseName;
    private Double jsePpu;
    private TesterBatters jseBatters;
    private List<TesterToppin> jseTopping;
    public String getTesterId() {
        return jseId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have to add constraint annotations such as `@NotNull`, `@Size` etc. to the elements of your model (i.e. the properties and/or classes) and perform a validation of these constraints at a suitable point of time (e.g. when persisting objects or processing data entered by the user into a GUI) using the `javax.validation.Validator` API.

To recursively apply a validation to referenced objects, use the `@Valid` annotation.

I recommend to have a look into the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/) which explains in detail how to work with Bean Validation.